# Exponential integral equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to find the function $q(x)$ such that the following integral equation is satisfied for all $s\ge 0$:
$$
\frac{p}{as + 1}\int_0^\infty  \exp \left( -\frac{xs}{as + 1} \right)q(x)dx 
= \frac{p-1}{bs + 1}\int_0^\infty  \exp \left( -\frac{xs}{bs + 1} \right)q(x)dx 
$$
where constants: $p \in (0,1)$ and $0< a <b$.

I have tried solving it for a while. However, I am stuck. I was hoping that someone could give me a hint.

Comment: How about $q(x)=0$?

Comment: Have you tried to bring the denominator in front of the integral on both sides, within the integral and combine with the exponential to form a derivative with respect to x? (I am on my phone so I can't show what I mean concretely)